# Inconsistent points between meta and main

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

In SQA.main I have 1,128 points, and in SQA.meta 1,118 as shown in the top bar. Is this by design? Delay in synchronization?

Update 20 min later: Now it got synced, still this is interesting case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reputation is synced on the hour, if it's out of sync for way longer than that, let us know!